# DataFrameGroupBy object Column Name

Tags: python, pandas, rename, dataframe

I have a DataFrameGroupBy object (i.e. it's not a dataframe but a grouped by dataframe) that has duplicate column name.
How do I change one of the duplicate column name. ( use of .rename has been unsuccessful)

Since there are two column names with the same 'label' how do I keep one of the column name intact and change the other column name.
Thanks

As an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Stock' : ['apple', 'ford', 'google', 'samsung','walmart', 'kroger'],
                       'Sector' : ['tech', 'auto', 'tech', 'tech','retail', 'retail'],
                       'Price': np.random.randn(6),
                       'Signal' : np.random.randn(6)},  columns= ['Stock','Sector','Price','Signal'])
    dfg = df.groupby([df['Sector'],df['Price'],(df.Price*2)])
    dfg.head()
```

-The above will result in two column named 'Price' in the DataFrameGroupBy.
I want to keep the 'Price' column and rename the other one as 'PriceSquared'.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not just calculate the column before you group?

```
df['PriceSquared'] = df['Price'] * 2
dfg = df.groupby(['Sector', 'Price', 'PriceSquared'])
```

EDIT:
As far as I'm aware, the two ways to rename a series are:

```
s = df.Price * 2
s.name = 'PriceSquared'
```

or

```
s = pd.Series(df.Price * 2, name='PriceSquared')
```

Comment: Yes, certainly that can be done. I am however looking for a way not to solve the particular problem, but trying to figure out an answer to ' how to change Column Name ' when duplicate column name exists in a DataFrameGroupBy object. Thanks,

Comment: @user3923585 - see edit for you might accomplish that

Comment: Thanks, Unfortunately it doesn't answer the question 'How do I change  one of the duplicate column name in a  **'DataFrameGroupBy object'**

Comment: I guess I don't understand why you'd ever need to do that so I'm not sure there's exposed functionality to do so.  Creating the GroupBy object doesn't really 'do' anything (just defines a mapping but no real computation) so it'd always be just as efficient to change column names before passing to a GroupBy.